# Horizontal line that take up the rest of the space to the right of text with multiple line

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/wv3hmub1/14/

I want to achive this

```
Header --------------------
```

or

```
My Header many letters
second line ---------------
```

I tried this:

```html
<div class="max-width">
  <h5 class="h-line">Horizontal line not displayed when too many letters </h5>
</div>

<div class="max-width">
  <h5 class="h-line">Horizontal line visible</h5>
</div>
```

and CSS

```css
.max-width {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.h-line {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.h-line::after {
    content: "";
    flex: 1 1;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: rgb(100, 91, 91);
}
```

It works fine for one line text, but horizontal line is not displayed for multiple lines header.
Example code https://jsfiddle.net/wv3hmub1/14/

How to display the horizontal line for multiple line headers? (add one red line)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
  you can achieve that by making the height of the box 0.5em than displaying its border-top only. example:

.h-line {
position: relative; }

.h-line::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 0.5em;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    z-index: -1;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like below:

```css
.max-width {
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden; /* you need this to hide the overflow */
}

.h-line::after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle; /* middle of the text */
  margin-left: .5rem;
  height: 2px; /* control the height of the line */
  border-image: linear-gradient(rgb(100, 91, 91) 0 0) fill 0//0 100vw 0 0; /* the color here */
}
```

```html
<div class="max-width">
  <h5 class="h-line">Horizontal line not displayed when too many letters </h5>
</div>

<div class="max-width">
  <h5 class="h-line">Horizontal line visible</h5>
</div>
```

Comment: The border-image trick is not intuitive but I will soon have an article about it that I will link to this answer when it's live